# Normal mapping giving wierd results. (C# XNA)

Tags: c#, xna, shader

Okay, so this problem is kinda huge, and for the same reason i would rather post as little code as possible, but rather have you come with ideas as to what it could be. I will post the codere where i feel the problem could be. If you would like to see more just ask and i will provide it.

So, i just "stole" a shader for my game. By stole i mean found a tutorial that i had done before, and just copied the end result. Thus i know the shader should work, because i've used it before.

I have a custom mesh class, and also a custom vertex struct. I have never done a xertex struct before so initially i thought this is where the problem was.
But i have some counterarguments i later found:
All of their variables seems to be right, and everything works except the bump-mapping.
Changing the Tangent and/or binormal seems to have no effect on the shading what-so-ever. So i think the mistake is not in how they are calulated, but rather how they are used.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/w6kv.png/

This is the output i get. Keep in mind that this is a voxel engine. As you can see all the boxes has the same wierd normal-map shadow. However this is the normal map:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/268/r7jt.jpg/

As you can see, they don't fit whatsoever. Now, this could be one of three things as i see it:

1. It could be the way i set up the shader in xna.
2. It could also be something in the vertex struct
3. It could also be the way i call the actual drawing function.

So here's the code for those three things (And the shader as well):

Shader Setup:
((Here i set up the data for the shader, and the draw the mesh))

```
// Bind the parameters with the shader.
BBS.Parameters["World"].SetValue(Matrix.Identity);
BBS.Parameters["View"].SetValue(camera.viewMatrix);
BBS.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(camera.projectionMatrix);

BBS.Parameters["AmbientColor"].SetValue(Color.White.ToVector4());
BBS.Parameters["AmbientIntensity"].SetValue(0.5f);

Vector3 LD = new Vector3(0, 1, -1);
LD.Normalize();

BBS.Parameters["DiffuseColor"].SetValue(Color.White.ToVector4());
BBS.Parameters["DiffuseIntensity"].SetValue(0);
BBS.Parameters["LightDirection"].SetValue(LD);

BBS.Parameters["EyePosition"].SetValue(new Vector3(0.0f, 2.0f, 5.0f));
BBS.Parameters["SpecularColor"].SetValue(Color.White.ToVector4());
BBS.Parameters["ColorMap"].SetValue(cubeTexture);
BBS.Parameters["NormalMap"].SetValue(Content.Load<Texture2D>("images"));


BBS.CurrentTechnique = BBS.Techniques["Technique1"];

for (int i = 0; i < BBS.CurrentTechnique.Passes.Count; i++)
{
    //EffectPass.Apply will update the device to
    //begin using the state information defined in the current pass
    BBS.CurrentTechnique.Passes[i].Apply();

    //theMesh contains all of the information required to draw
    //the current mesh
    graphics.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, Mesh.Vertices, 0, Mesh.NUM_TRIANGLES);
}
```

Vertex struct:

```
public struct VertexPositionNormalTangentBinormalTexture : IVertexType
{ 
    public Vector3 Position; 
    public Vector3 Normal; 
    public Vector2 TextureCoordinate; 
    public Vector3 Tangent; 
    public Vector3 Binormal;

    public static readonly VertexDeclaration VertexElements = new VertexDeclaration
    ( 
        new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0), 
        new VertexElement(12, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Normal, 0), 
        new VertexElement(24, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0), 
        new VertexElement(32, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Tangent, 0), 
        new VertexElement(44, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Binormal, 0)
    );


    VertexDeclaration IVertexType.VertexDeclaration { get { return VertexElements; } }

    public static readonly int SizeInBytes = sizeof(float) * (3 + 3 + 2 + 3 + 3);
}
```

Shader:

```
    // XNA 4.0 Shader Programming #4 - Normal Mapping

// Matrix
float4x4 World;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;

// Light related
float4 AmbientColor;
float AmbientIntensity;

float3 LightDirection;
float4 DiffuseColor;
float DiffuseIntensity;

float4 SpecularColor;
float3 EyePosition;


texture2D ColorMap;
sampler2D ColorMapSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <ColorMap>;
    MinFilter = linear;
    MagFilter = linear;
    MipFilter = linear;
};

texture2D NormalMap;
sampler2D NormalMapSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <NormalMap>;
    MinFilter = linear;
    MagFilter = linear;
    MipFilter = linear;
};

// The input for the VertexShader
struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 Normal : NORMAL0;
    float3 Binormal : BINORMAL0;
    float3 Tangent : TANGENT0;
};

// The output from the vertex shader, used for later processing
struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 View : TEXCOORD1;
    float3x3 WorldToTangentSpace : TEXCOORD2;
};

// The VertexShader.
VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
    output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);
    output.TexCoord = input.TexCoord;

    output.WorldToTangentSpace[0] = mul(normalize(input.Tangent), World);
    output.WorldToTangentSpace[1] = mul(normalize(input.Binormal), World);
    output.WorldToTangentSpace[2] = mul(normalize(input.Normal), World);

    output.View = normalize(float4(EyePosition,1.0) - worldPosition);

    return output;
}

// The Pixel Shader
float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
    float4 color = tex2D(ColorMapSampler, input.TexCoord);

    float3 normalMap = 2.0 *(tex2D(NormalMapSampler, input.TexCoord)) - 1.0;
    normalMap = normalize(mul(normalMap, input.WorldToTangentSpace));
    float4 normal = float4(normalMap,1.0);

    float4 diffuse = saturate(dot(-LightDirection,normal));
    float4 reflect = normalize(2*diffuse*normal-float4(LightDirection,1.0));
    float4 specular = pow(saturate(dot(reflect,input.View)),32);

    return  color * AmbientColor * AmbientIntensity + 
            color * DiffuseIntensity * DiffuseColor * diffuse + 
            color * SpecularColor * specular;
}

// Our Techinique
technique Technique1
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VertexShaderFunction();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Is Not Done In The Correct Order:

```
output.WorldToTangentSpace[0] = mul(normalize(input.Tangent), World);
output.WorldToTangentSpace[1] = mul(normalize(input.Binormal), World);
output.WorldToTangentSpace[2] = mul(normalize(input.Normal), World);
```

It Should Be Like This:

```
output.WorldToTangentSpace[0] = normalize(mul(input.Tangent, World));
output.WorldToTangentSpace[1] = normalize(mul(input.Binormal, World));
output.WorldToTangentSpace[2] = normalize(mul(input.Normal, World));
```

Otherwise, Your Normals Will Get Scaled From The World-space Transformation And Will Result In Very Bright And Very Dark Patches (Which Looks Like Your Problem). BTW, Seeing As You're Interested In Normal Mapping For Voxel Engines, Check Out The Following That I Had Made:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roMlOmNgr_w
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkfHoGzQ8ZY

Hope You Get Inspired And That You Complete Your Project.

Comment: Do you mean `normalize(mul(input.Tangent, World))` (rather than `normalize(mul(input.Tangent), World)`)?